# corruption converting from Unix Epoch time in C

Tags: c, datetime, struct

I have this simple C project that I'm having an issue with that I can't seem to resolve.  With the 3 lines of code commented out, the code will produce this correct result:

```
1st Printing of Timestamp (UTC): 08/19/2023 15:04:48  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)
2nd Printing of Timestamp (UTC): 08/19/2023 15:04:48  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)
```

However, if I uncomment the 3 lines of code, I get these results:

```
1st Printing of Timestamp (UTC): 08/19/2023 15:04:48  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)
2nd Printing of Timestamp (UTC): 08/19/2023 20:27:57  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)
```

where the "2nd Printing" produces the **present** MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS instead of the correct result.  **Those 3 lines of code should have no effect** on anything - but they do and I can't see what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    // Get a Unix epoch value
    long long timestamp_ms = 1692457488113;
    char formatted_time[50]; // only need 20 characters to hold "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"

    // Convert Unix timestamp to "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS" format in UTC time
    time_t timestamp_seconds = (time_t)(timestamp_ms / 1000); // Convert milliseconds to seconds
    struct tm *timestamp_timeinfo = gmtime(&timestamp_seconds); // Use gmtime for UTC time

    // print result - should be 08/19/2023 15:04:48  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)
    strftime(formatted_time, sizeof(formatted_time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", timestamp_timeinfo);
    printf("1st Printing of Timestamp (UTC): %s  (Unix Epoch time: %lld)\n", formatted_time, timestamp_ms/1000);

       
/*    time_t current_utc_time; // Get current UTC time  grabbing variabluse I do nothing with (suspect gmtime memory leak)
      time(&current_utc_time);
      struct tm *current_timeinfo = gmtime(&current_utc_time);  
*/


    // print again, should be "08/19/2023 15:04:48  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)" but it is not
    strftime(formatted_time, sizeof(formatted_time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", timestamp_timeinfo);
    printf("2nd Printing of Timestamp (UTC): %s  (Unix Epoch time: %lld)\n", formatted_time, timestamp_ms/1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `gmtime` returns a pointer to an internal struct. So when you call it a 2nd time, the data that `timestamp_timeinfo` is pointing to (from the previous call to `gmtime`) gets overwritten.

Comment: I think @001 is correct. You can probably use `gmtime_r()` to work around that.

Comment: Thank you both (@001 & @pmacfarlane).  I didn't realize that `gmtime()`  behavoir.  Agree `gmtime_r()` is way to go.  If @001 will make an answer I'll accept it.  [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least these issues:

**Not checking the return value**

`gmtime()` and `time()` may return `NULL`, `-1` indicating a failure.  Robust code tests that.

**Re-using the `struct tm` from `gtmtime()`**

Each call to `gmtime()` and `localtime()` returns a pointer to the same `struct tm`.  When needing to keep the prior value, save the contents.

---

Sample re-write

```
int main(void) {
    long long timestamp_ms = 1692457488113;
    char formatted_time[50]; // only need 20 characters to hold "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"

    time_t timestamp_seconds = (time_t)(timestamp_ms / 1000); // Convert milliseconds to seconds
    struct tm *timestamp_timeinfo = gmtime(&timestamp_seconds); // Use gmtime for UTC time
    if (timestamp_timeinfo == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failure to convert\n");
      return -1;
    }
    struct tm t1 = *timestamp_timeinfo;

    // print result - should be 08/19/2023 15:04:48  (Unix Epoch time: 1692457488)
    if (0 == strftime(formatted_time, sizeof(formatted_time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &t1)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failure strtime\n");
      return -1;
    }
    printf("1st Printing of Timestamp (UTC): %s  (Unix Epoch time: %lld)\n", formatted_time, timestamp_ms/1000);

       
    time_t current_utc_time; // Get current UTC time
    if (time(&current_utc_time) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failure to convert\n");
      return -1;
    }
    struct tm *current_timeinfo = gmtime(&current_utc_time);  
    if (current_timeinfo == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failure to convert\n");
      return -1;
    }

    // print again
    strftime(formatted_time, sizeof(formatted_time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &t1);
    printf("2nd Printing of Timestamp (UTC): %s  (Unix Epoch time: %lld)\n", formatted_time, timestamp_ms/1000);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Side issue:

`char formatted_time[50]; // only need 20 characters to hold "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"` is risky and trip code checkers as the `struct tm` members accessed are `int` and they *may* have values as long as a text versions of `INT_MIN`.  What if the year was 5 digit?  `strftime()` does not assume the members are in their primary range, nor should the rest of code.  Best to scale a generous buffer per the format.

Rather than be stingy with buffer space, be generous.

```
#define TIME_FMT "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
#define INT_LEN 11
#define FTIME_SIZE (6 * INT_LEN + sizeof(TIME_FMT))

char formatted_time[FTIME_SIZE];
strftime(formatted_time, sizeof(formatted_time), TIME_FMT, &t1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra tutoring, needed and welcomed.